# RecyclerView wants to add item on position out of list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have just started using short and sweet [Searchable RecyclerView](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo) and it works fine until I have to use `addItem()`. After deleting one letter `mModels` list size is 237 (see `count` on picture), but while adding item it's size is 104 and mysteriously when it hits item that wants to be on 105th position it throws `java.lang.OutOfBoundsException`. From String that those objects provide it just wants to be the last item on the list at the moment. Original repo is working fine even while adding item that wants to be on the list end. I have no clue what to do with this now.

And yes, filtering works just great. It's just adding item when I take chars of the query it's causing problems.

[image]

Adapter code:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tvBeerName;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvBeerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
    }

    public void bind(PiwoSubclass model) {
        tvBeerName.setText(model.getBeerName());
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final List<PiwoSubclass> mModels;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<PiwoSubclass> models) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
}

@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view_new, parent, false);
    return new ExampleViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PiwoSubclass model = mModels.get(position);
    holder.bind(model);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModels.size();
}

public void animateTo(List<PiwoSubclass> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<PiwoSubclass> newModels) {
    for (int i = mModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final PiwoSubclass model = mModels.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<PiwoSubclass> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final PiwoSubclass model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mModels.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<PiwoSubclass> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final PiwoSubclass model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mModels.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public PiwoSubclass removeItem(int position) {
    final PiwoSubclass model = mModels.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, PiwoSubclass model) {
    Log.d("Position-item", position + "");
    mModels.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final PiwoSubclass model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
    mModels.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
}
```

Fragment's excerpt:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        final List<PiwoSubclass> filteredModelList = filter(mModels, query);
        mAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
        Log.d("List-size", "Size: " + filteredModelList.size());
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }

    private List<PiwoSubclass> filter(List<PiwoSubclass> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<PiwoSubclass> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PiwoSubclass model : models) {
            final String beerName = model.getBeerName().toLowerCase();
            //final String breweryName = model.getBrewery().toLowerCase();
            if (beerName.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

Comment: Do share some code for the adapter.

Comment: @vipulmittal updated my question

Comment: How do you set the newModel

Comment: @vipulmittal I don't have to. I pass already filtered list to `animateTo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<PiwoSubclass> newModels) {

    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final PiwoSubclass model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mModels.contains(model)) {
            addItem(0, model);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this,  "addItem(0, model);". This will always add the items in 0th position. Please Let me know the result

Comment: Wierdly I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 236, size is 232` when I thought it would be just unordered, but know I comes from `moveItem()` method